# Rails sort query by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I have Payment, Invoice, and Transaction models setup like this:

```
# transaction.rb
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :transactionable, polymorphic: true
end

# payment.rb
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable
end

# invoice.rb
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable
end
```

In my customers show template, I'm finding all transactions that belong to the requested customer. I want to sort the the transactions by the date of the Invoice or Payment that they belong to. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])

    # I want the transactions sorted by the date of the Invoice or Payment they belong to 
    @transactions = Transaction.where(customer: @customer)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible with scopes.

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
transactions = Transaction.all
transactions = transactions.order_by_payment_date
transactions = transactions.order_by_invoice_date
transactions = transactions.includes_transactionable

transactions.each do |transaction|
  # do what you want with the transaction and transactable
end
```

Hopefully this code just works:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :transactionable, polymorphic: true

  scope :includes_transactionable, -> { includes(:transactionable) }

  scope :order_by_payment_date, -> {
    # This may or may not work, you may need to specify a has_many 
    # relationship to Payment, or do more to get the join to work
    joins(Payment.arel_table).merge( Payment.descending )
  }

  scope :order_by_invoice_date, -> {
    # This may or may not work, you may need to specify a has_many 
    # relationship to Invoice, or do more to get the join to work
    joins(Invoice.arel_table).merge( Invoice.descending )
  }
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable

  scope :descending, -> { order(arel_table[:payment_date].desc) }
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable

  scope :descending, -> { order(arel_table[:invoice_date].desc) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If a transaction is always created alongside a payment or invoice, you could use the `created_at` timestamp on the transactions table.  If not however, in an effort to keep the transaction model from specifically knowing which models it can belong to, a good option would be to create another datetime column on the transactions table, and have it be updated with whatever datetime is most relevant in the associated object.

Comment: I agree with this solution, the relevant `transaction time` should be recorded on the `Transaction` separate from any time of the `Invoice` or `Payment`.

Comment: This would work, but if I wanted to sort transactions by other values such as the amount of the payment or invoice, I'll have to add those columns to the transactions table as well. This seems redundant.